# Solr: Set a different weight (boost) at each value of a field (with multivalued=true)

Tags: solr, solr4, dataimporthandler, solr-boost

- I'm using Solr4.4.
- I'm using DIH with RDBMS

I need to set a different weight (boost) at each value of a field (with multivalued=true).
In particular, I have a field (text - with multivalued=true) and a float value different for each text, and I would to set that float value as boost at each text of the field.

```
id - 1
myText: "iphone ipad", "iphone", "ipad"
myFloatValue: 2.3, 4.1, 1.6
```

In my db-dataimport.xml file

```
<entity name="item"
query="SELECT myText,
                  myFloatValue
         FROM myTable
             WHERE myCondition" >
      <field name="myText" column="myText" boost="${item.myFloatValue}" />
```

It return an error:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Data Config problem: For input string: "{$places.distance_place}"
    at
```

I also tried to set in my query a Cast:

```
SELECT myText,
  CAST(myFloatValue AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as myFloatValue
  FROM myTable
 WHERE myCondition
```

I hope that is clear my situation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a solution now?

Comment: not yet :(, do you have any suggests?

Comment: No. I meet the same problem. :(

Comment: Hi @Lynn do you solve your problem?

Comment: @Dnay No. How about you?

Comment: @Lynn no but i need it.